# Compiled iOS app automatically opens keyboard on start

Tags: livecode

I have a program that works correctly in the iOS simulator, but does not work correctly when loaded onto an iOS device (my iPad mini, running iOS 8)

Once the app is launched, the on-screen keyboard automatically opens up. There are no editable fields that are visible on my card. (There is some title text, but the fields are locked.)

I have no commands in `preOpenStack`, `openStack`, `preOpenCard`, etc...

Any advice on how to prevent this?

Comment: Are you using any externals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, when the card opens, there is a field that gets focus. Perhaps you think a field is locked but it isn't. It can also be a combobox or datagrid that gets focus. Probably, the best way to test this is to run the following script before compiling your app:

```
on lockFields
  repeat with x = 1 to the number of fields
    set the lockText of field x to true
  end repeat
end lockFields
```

Run this script once to lock all fields. Now do a test and see if the keyboard shows up. If you have any comboboxes, include them in the script separately, adding something like the following to it:

```
  repeat for each item myItem in "Combobox 1,Combobox 2,Combobox 3"
    disable btn myItem
  end repeat
```

Once you know which control is causing the problem, you can add another script to the card:

```
on enableControls
  repeat for each item myItem in "Field A,Field B,Combobox 1,Combobox 2"
    enable control myItem
    if the name of control myItem contains "field" then
      set the lockText of control myItem to false
    end if
  end repeat
end enableControls
```

After running this handler, the fields and comboBoxes should be focusable, but the keyboard should not appear.

Important is also that you have no script laying around that creates a native field (which is invisible). If you create such a native field, the keyboard would also appear.

Comment: Thanks Mark, locking the fields didn't work, but the combobox suggestion did, so that was the culprit, and this helped me narrow down which one it was and I told it who's boss.